# user enter data and store in array, show the data by null entry

Tags: javascript

that not showing result for exit i use return for showing the array data use list

'''

```
    let list = [], name;
    while (name = prompt("ENTER A NAME :")) {
        list.push(name);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        alert(list[i]);
    }
    if (name === null) {
    return;
}
```

'''
How do I check the return value in this

Comment: please reformulate your question, it's very confusing

Answer (score 0):

If you enter nothing, it gets an empty string.

```
const x = prompt();

console.log(x === '');
```

so if you check this out, it returns `true`

All you need to do is check if its empty string or not.